# Show current page on Drupal 7 breadcrumb

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

Is there anyway to add the current page title on drupal 7 breadcrumb?

Comment: just implemented this on my theme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some themes - like Zen - provide this option, so check under Appearance -> Settings.  If your theme doesn't offer the option, you can edit your theme's page.tpl.php - simply add `$title` after the `$breadcrumb` variable.  Alternatively you could override [`theme_breadcrumb()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the [Menu breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) module to do this (it has D6 and D7 versions too).
It allows you to

> *"Append the page title to the breadcrumb (either as a clickable url or
>   not)"*

See this tutorial:
[Tutorial - How to Work and Style Breadcrumbs in Drupal 7](http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/tutorial-how-work-and-style-breadcrumbs-drupal-7)

[image: Menu breadcrumb]

[image: Menu breadcrumb - It uses the menu hierarchy to determine the breadcrumb trails.]

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, if you are coding your breadcrumb trail in the template.php file, the page title will be added in the breadcrumbs to any [custompage].tpl.php file automatically.

I am not saying it's a *better* way of doing it. Personally, it was a more convenient solution for me, as i have multiple [page].tpl.php files.

(I also changed the default output to `<li>` list items, in order to get the CSS markup right.)

```
function templatename_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  $crumbs = '';
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $crumbs = '<div id="breadcrumbs"><span>You are here: </span><ul>';
    foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
      $crumbs .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }
    $crumbs .= '<li>' . drupal_get_title() . '</li></ul></div>';
  }
  return $crumbs;
}
```

Maybe this is of some help to anyone.

Comment: did you notice the page title is not inside a <li>?

Comment: ah, yes, I had left out some parts of my code of which I thought they were irrelevant in my answer. Apparently, I was a bit too enthousiastic in stripping the code. Thank you for noticing, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Custom Breadcrumbs module](http://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) it has an option where you can include the current page title (or any other token field)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have breadcrumb in a block, you can create a block with the following content:

```
<?php   
$bcarr = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
$bcarr [] = drupal_get_title();
print  theme('breadcrumb', array('breadcrumb'=>$bcarr));
?>
```

This is for Drupal 7 and the content type should be PHP code.